# Condition based in strings contained in groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
             A      B   C
0   2002-01-12  Sarah  39
1   2002-01-12   John  17
2   2002-01-12  Susan  30
3   2002-01-15  Danny  12
4   2002-01-15  Peter  25
5   2002-01-15   John  25
6   2002-01-20   John  16
7   2002-01-20   Hung  10
8   2002-02-20   John  20
9   2002-02-20  Susan  40
10  2002-02-24  Rebel  40
11  2002-02-24  Susan  15
12  2002-02-24   Mark  38
13  2002-02-24  Susan  30
```

I want to select full `A` groups that contain `John` and `Susan`.

Output should be:

```
             A      B   C
0   2002-01-12  Sarah  39
1   2002-01-12   John  17
2   2002-01-12  Susan  30
6   2002-01-20   John  16
7   2002-01-20   Hung  10
8   2002-02-20   John  20
9   2002-02-20  Susan  40
```

I've tried:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: ((df.B == x.John) & (df.B == x.Susan)))
```

Comment: `2002-01-20` doesn't contain `Susan`, yet is in your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `transform` to create a flag for the groups that satisfy that condition. And then you can mask the original `df` by that flag. If you don't want to modify the original `df` you can create a separate `Series` named `flag`, otherwise you can also just assign it to a column in your original `df`

```
import pandas as pd
# As Haleemur Ali points out, use x.values to make it faster
flag = df.groupby('A').B.transform(lambda x: (x.values == 'Susan').any() & (x.values == 'John').any())
```

Then you can filter the `df`

```
df[flag]
#            A      B   C
#0  2002-01-12  Sarah  39
#1  2002-01-12   John  17
#2  2002-01-12  Susan  30
#8  2002-02-20   John  20
#9  2002-02-20  Susan  40
```

Answer (score 2):

create an array of dates as the intersection of dates that contain `John` & dates that contain `Susan`:

```
dates = np.intersect1d(
    df.A.values[df.B.values == 'John'], 
    df.A.values[df.B.values == 'Susan']
)
```

then use the dates array to filter the dataframe

```
df[df.A.isin(dates)]

# outputs:
            A      B   C
0  2002-01-12  Sarah  39
1  2002-01-12   John  17
2  2002-01-12  Susan  30
8  2002-02-20   John  20
9  2002-02-20  Susan  40
```

#### Timings:

Comparing the solutions provided by [jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9209546/jpp), [ALollz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333359/alollz) and mine above:

The numpy based solution is several times more efficient than the others.

```
In [288]: def hal(df):
     ...:     dates = np.intersect1d(
     ...:      df.A.values[df.B.values == 'John'], 
     ...:      df.A.values[df.B.values == 'Susan']
     ...:     )
     ...:     return df[df.A.isin(dates)]
     ...:

In [289]: def jpp(df):
     ...:     s = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(set)
     ...:     return df[df['A'].map(s) >= {'John', 'Susan'}]
     ...:

In [290]: def alollz(df):
     ...:     flag = df.groupby('A').B.transform(lambda x: ((x=='Susan').any() & (x == 'John').any()).sum().astype('boo
     ...: l'))
     ...:     return df[flag==True]
     ...:

In [291]: %timeit hal(df)
394 µs ± 6.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [292]: %timeit jpp(df)
1.46 ms ± 27.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [293]: %timeit alollz(df)
4.9 ms ± 75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

However, the solution proposed by ALollz can be sped up 2X by omitting some extra unneeded operations and going down to numpy arrays for comparison.

```
In [294]: def alollz_improved(df):
     ...:     v = df.groupby('A').B.transform(lambda x: (x.values=='Susan').any() & (x.values=='John').any())
     ...:     return df[v]
     ...:

In [295]: %timeit alollz_improved(df)
2.2 ms ± 38.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Yeah. I quickly realized I had a few unnecessary operations. :p. Not sure why your answer got a downvote, it's succinct. Actually, the true time difference seems to be in using `x.values` instead of `x`.

Comment: Thanks, I like your approach. its straight-forward. Not sure about the downvote. it would be nicer if the downvoter would point out areas of improvement

Answer (score 1):

Create a series mapping each date to a `set` of names. Then use [`set.issuperset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) via syntactic sugar `>=`:

```
s = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(set)

res = df[df['A'].map(s) >= {'John', 'Susan'}]

print(res)

            A      B   C
0  2002-01-12  Sarah  39
1  2002-01-12   John  17
2  2002-01-12  Susan  30
8  2002-02-20   John  20
9  2002-02-20  Susan  40
```